# How to prove with conditional branches in Idris?

Tags: proof, idris

I'm trying to implement the McCarthy91 function in Idris and prove some properties of it (The full code is [here](https://gist.github.com/Axure/cb7db8f3ce7a6258bc896c2d86a1a199)). But I encountered a problem here.

The function is defined by splitting into two cases: > 100 and <= 100. To achieve this I defined a type level function `isLte` (pretty much in the same spirit as the one in the standard library):

```
data (<=): (x, y: Peano) -> Type where
  OLte: (x: Peano) -> O <= x
  SLte: x <= y -> ((++)x) <= ((++)y)

total
isLte: (x, y: Peano) -> Result (x <= y) ((++)y <= x)
isLte O x = Yes (OLte x)
isLte ((++)x) O = No (SLte (OLte x))
isLte ((++)x) ((++)y) = case isLte x y of
  No revLteProof => No (SLte revLteProof)
  Yes lteProof => Yes (SLte lteProof)

mcCarthy: Peano -> Peano
mcCarthy n = case n `isLte` Main.hundred of
  No hundredOneLteN => totalMinus (trans tenLteHundredOne hundredOneLteN)
  Yes lteProof => mcCarthy (mcCarthy (n + Main.eleven))
```

What I want to prove could be written as:

```
mcCarthyIdentity2: (hundredOneLteX: Main.hundredOne <= x) -> mcCarthy x = totalMinus (trans Main.tenLteHundredOne hundredOneLteX)

mcCarthyIdentity: n <= Main.hundred -> mcCarthy x = Main.ninetyOne
```

The problem is, how do I tell Idris that `n <= Main.hundred`, e.g., will let `mcCarthy n` fall into the second branch of the case? Simply `rewrite` or `Refl` does not seem to work.

A more simple problem (which may or may not be directly relevant) could be proving:

```
total
f: Nat -> Nat
f x = if x > 10 then 1 else 2

total
proofOfF: x < 4 -> f x = 2
-- What to write?
```

How can I actually tell Idris that the condition has something to do with the branches?

Comment: Hi @Colliot, I haven't tried to prove it in Idris, because right now I don't have working version of Idris. I proved it in Coq, and the main idea is you assume that  10 < x or 10 >= x because of decidability of nat. In first case, we have contradiction, because of 10 < x and x < 4. Second case is just reflexivity.
https://gist.github.com/mukeshtiwari/317b608c743161ba25469ff75cdf86bb